# How does one merge two sequences together based on a primary key?

Tags: merge, f#, primary-key

I am curious how one merges two sequences in F# based on a primary key.
I have not tried anything because I have no idea where to begin.

Example:

Original Two Sets:

```
ID Cash
(1,$5)
(2,$10)
(3,$5)

ID Car
(1,Yes) 
(2,No)
(3,Yes)
```

Result:

```
ID Cash Car
(1,$5,Yes)
(2,$10,No)
(3,$5,Yes)
```

Comment: are those Sets (no duplicates) or just ordinary sequences?

Comment: ordinary sequences. meant to be at least

Comment: you can't have a sequence where one element is a string (like "ID"), and another is an integer (like 1).

Comment: yeah I know, I was trying to create the illusion of column names so it is easier to read. fixed it

Comment: You already messed up the column name order in your result :-)

Comment: any suggestions? on how to solve this problem?

Comment: you could create a Map/Dictionary with the key, and add the values from each sequence. Depends if you key is unique in the end or not.

Comment: Are there any duplicate IDs? Are there any IDs in one sequence that are skipped in the other sequence? If the answer to both these questions is no, then  the simplest way is to sort both sequences and then use [`Seq.map2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.map2%5b't1,'t2,'u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) to convert the two sequences into a single sequence that uses the values from both.

Comment: there are not multiple ID's but there might be ID's that are not in one sequence but in the other. @rmunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably would be using [query expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) to solve your problem.

Given this data set:

```
let cashList = [ (1, 5); (2, 10); (3, 5) ]
let carList = [ (1, "Yes"); (2, "No"); (3, "Yes") ]
```

The following query should do the trick:

```
let result = query {
  for cash in cashList do
  join car in carList on (fst cash = fst car)
  select (fst cash, snd cash, snd car)
}
```

Comment: I really like the query expression, but what if cashList has a key, that's not in carList. Which is a possibility looking at the last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, based on some of your comments.

This is your starting data, a list of (int, string) tuples

```
let seq1 = [(1,"$5");(2,"$10");(3,"$5")]    
let seq2 = [(1,"Yes");(2,"No");(3,"Yes")]
```

We generate the unique keys and make a union:

```
let keys1 = seq1 |> List.map fst |> Set.ofList 
let keys2 = seq2 |> List.map fst |> Set.ofList
let keys3 = keys1 + keys2
```

We also make a dictionary from the two sequences to make the lookup easier:

```
let map1 = Map.ofList seq1
let map2 = Map.ofList seq2
```

Finally, we go through all the keys, and pull the corresponding values from both maps. To account for the fact that some keys might be missing, I used `TryFind`:

```
keys3
    |> Set.map (fun x -> 
                let val1 = map1.TryFind(x)
                let val2 = map2.TryFind(x)
                (x,val1,val2)
    )

//val it : Set<int * string option * string option> =
//  set [(1, Some "$5", Some "Yes"); (2, Some "$10", Some "No");
//     (3, Some "$5", Some "Yes")]
```

Now you can convert this set back to a list or a dictionary, get rid of the Nones, etc.